# Problems installing Chrome in SLED 11

Tags: rpm, chrome, suse

I'm trying to install Google Chrome on my OS, but when I execute the `.rpm`, I got this error:

```
google-chrome-stable-35.0.1916.153-1.x86_64 requires libX11.so.6 (64bit), but this requirement cannot be provided.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install it manually. As this lib is not available in default SELD yum repository. You can try installing [this rpm](ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/suser-jmorris/suse92/xorg-x11-libs-6.8.2-0.1.x86_64.rpm) manually.

Answer (score 0):

You need an rpm built for SLED 11 - the error you see means that the package has been compiled and linked against versions of libraries not available on your system.

You may want to have a look at the [openSUSE software portal](http://software.opensuse.org/), there might be a Chromium build for SLED. If not and you are fine with playing a little bit with creating packages than you can create an account on the [openSUSE Buildservice](http://build.opensuse.org), branch the package to your home project and try to build it for SLE11 (this can all be done from a web browser).

Apart from that I would suggest giving Firefox or SeaMonkey a try.